# Contar total de una tabla y agrupar por pedido

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de pedidos en la cual almaceno todos los pedidos de la web. Como un pedido puede llevar más de un producto es = a que si hay dos productos hay dos filas en la sql pero realmente hay un solo pedido.

Para hacer esto, los agrupo por numero de pedido con un numero consecutivo.

Pero a nivel estadistico quiero sacar el número total de pedidos que hay en la tabla, pero no puede contar todas las filas, ya que no es lo mismo las filas que los pedidos.

Alguna sugerencia??

```
$cont = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(idpedido) as total  from pedidos");
            if($data = $cont->fetch_array()){}
```

Ahora mismo lo hago así, pero claro así me saca todos los resultados de la tabla. Tengo que hacer que cuente pero por grupo de pedidos o algo así, no se como.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes usar `distinct` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT idpedido) as total  from pedidos
```

Espero sea lo que estas buscando.

, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, mira que probe con el `DISTINCT` pero no de ese modo, gracias!